# how can I use a resw resources file inside a class library UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, class-library

I create a Class Library (Universal Windows UWP) project that contains and uses inside some .resw resources files but if these are found in the class library project are not loaded during the execution of the dll from the projects that use the dll. Everything works well only if I include resw files directly in the projects that use this dll, but I have to avoid this.

The Class Library get the resources map at this way (LocalizationLettersWords is a .resw file located in the Class Library project)

```
 ResourceMap lettersResourceMap = ResourceManager.Current.MainResourceMap.GetSubtree("LocalizationLettersWords");
```

but lettersResourceMap gets null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In UWP the `ResourceLoader` class is used for getting resources programmatically. So you can use this:

```
string resource1 = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView().GetString("YourKey");
```

but it'll not work when it's used on non-UI thread,. In that case you should use method `GetForViewIndependentUse`, for example:

```
string resource2 = ResourceLoader.GetForViewIndependentUse().GetString("YourKey");
```

You can read more about the `ResourceLoader` class [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.resources.resourceloader.aspx).

Comment: ok, but is there a way tu use ResourceMap and ResourceManager ?

Comment: to be honest, I don't know but if you need to load resources from different files, you can use GetForCurrentView("fileName") or GetForViewIndependentUse("fileName")

Comment: or maybe you could try this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e42fc337-f031-45a7-8313-b8d0cbfa43a5/uwp-do-windows-store-apps-support-localized-resources-in-assemblies-if-so-how-do-you-get-a?forum=wpdevelop